# Scrapy: Item discrepancy

Tags: scrapy

Scenario: a page with multiple items, each consisting of title, description, image. What happens when one of the items are missing the title? How does scrapy handle it? It seems that scrapy blindly selects all titles //div[id='content']/ul/li/div[id='title']/text(),

Expected output is that that row will have a missing title. But I fear that since it blindly selects all titles on the page without considering the item context. If the 5th item is missing title, wouldn't it mistakenly use the 6th item's title instead?

```
title1 | description | image
.
.
title4 | description | image
title6 | description | image  <--- it's supposed to be missing the title.
       | description | image
```

Does scrapy have a way to deal with this problem?

A workaround I was thinking would be to look at the parent item element, and then, look inside that item. If something is missing don't show it.

Comment: What are you using to select your xpath?  `HtmlXPathSelector`, `XPathItemLoader` or something else?

Comment: What is your Scrapy version, selectors version and os?  all available from the verbose *version* command: `$ scrapy version -v`

Comment: `HtmlXpathSElector` I am using the latest Scrapy version, Ubuntu 12.

Comment: The latest meaning 0.17 devel or 0.16 stable?  What version of lxml?  do you have libxml2 installed?  this information is available from the version command.  And you should paste in some of your code because it is not Scrapy that is blindly doing stuff... its your xpaths that ask for the data.

Comment: How would you implement this in Scrapy? I am simply using the basespider example, and I can see that using xpaths for pages with multiple data items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are variety of ways you can handle this situation

1) you can implement a pipeline that can skip items that are not required

2) you can add check in your extraction part to only yield/return an item that is required

you needs to understand Scrapy is a high level crawling Framework , that is also providing builten support for data extraction , you can use any library for extraction you would like to.

Comment: what are some built support for data extraction and where can I find those libraries?

Comment: HtmlXpathSElector  is a builten support , you can use lxml , beautifulsoup etc any one of your choice you like